# groupby multiple columns in a F# 3.0 query

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

Just trying out F# 3.0 and hit a bit of a wall when it comes to grouping by multiple columns. The obvious thing to try was

```
query {
    for d in context.table do
    groupBy (d.col1,d.col2) into g
    select (g.Key)
}
```

But I get a "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities." exception.

I can't seem to find an example on msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361035(v=vs.110).aspx

And I realize my question is similar to 
" [Entity Framework and Anonymous Types in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8546823/926042)" but it seems to be powerpack/F#2.x focused and I'm hoping F# 3.0 has an elegant answer... Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I came across the CLIMutable attribute from reading Brian's post at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx

I was pretty optimistic so I tried

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyRecord = { Column1 : int; Column2 : int }

query {
    for d in context.table do
    groupBy {Column1 = col1; Column2 = col2} into g
    select (g.Key)
}
```

Unfortunately I get the exact same exception.

Comment: Is the problem that you're grouping on a tuple, or that you're _selecting_ one? The error seems to refer to the "output" type. Maybe select `g.Count()` instead and see what happens. I haven't tried 3.0...just guessing.

Comment: I tried selecting a constant "select (1)" and got the same thing

Comment: @ildjarn: `g.Key` is a tuple, which doesn't have a parameterless constructor. `select 1` should work though, if my guess is correct.

Comment: @Daniel : `select g.Key` does not _construct or initialize_ a new tuple, however. AFAICT, `select (g.Key)` would be a `Tuple<Tuple<col1_t, col2_t>>`, which is invoking the constructor of `Tuple<'T1>`; `select g.Key` would be a `Tuple<col1_t, col2_t>`, reusing an existing value instead of initializing a new one. Of course, I'm running with the assumption that the exception is being caused by the `select` rather than the `groupBy`, which may be totally incorrect. :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: I could be way off, but I assumed the output would be `Tuple<_,_>` since he's grouping on `(d.col1,d.col2)` and selecting the key. It seems LINQ would have no way of instantiating such a type. Is the type of the query not determined by `select` as it is in C#?

Comment: @Daniel : Everything I've said is pure speculation -- I've no idea how the F#3 bits work (or are supposed to work). :-]

Comment: I checked "select (1)" in other contexts before hand to make sure it wasn't an issue on it's own. But I gave "select 1" and "select g.Key" a shot anyway and it's giving me the same thing.

Comment: The parenthesis is just for grouping. It is the commas that make it into a tuple. A tuple with only one element is entered as (1,)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is an example of multiple columns being used for grouping in c# and converted to f# (overly paranoid management has made me rename everything, but I believe I have been consistent):

(TheDatabase was generated by SqlMetal, GetSummedValuesResult is a F# record type)

c#

```
public static class Reports
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<GetSummedValuesResult> GetSummedValues(TheDatabase db, DateTime startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        var query =
            from sv in db.SomeValues

            where (sv.ADate >= startDate && sv.ADate <= (endDate ?? startDate))

            group sv by new { sv.ADate, sv.Owner.Name } into grouping

            select new GetSummedValuesResult(
                grouping.Key.ADate,
                grouping.Key.Name,
                grouping.Sum(g => g.Value)
            );

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

f#

```
type Reports() =
    static member GetSummedValues (db:TheDatabase) startDate (endDate:Nullable<DateTime>) =
        let endDate = if endDate.HasValue then endDate.Value else startDate

        let q = query {
            for sv in db.SomeValues do
            where (sv.ADate >= startDate && sv.ADate <= endDate)

            let key = AnonymousObject<_,_>(sv.ADate, sv.Owner.Name)
            groupValBy sv key into grouping

            select {
                ADate        = grouping.Key.Item1;
                AName        = grouping.Key.Item2;
                SummedValues = grouping.Sum (fun (g:TheDatabaseSchema.SomeValues) -> g.Value)
            }
        }

        List(q) :> IReadOnlyList<GetSummedValuesResult>
```

So the thing to use is `Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.AnonymousObject`

**Note that you should not use the Seq module for aggregation functions!!**

```
SummedValues  = grouping |> Seq.sumBy (fun g -> g.SomeValues)
```

Although this WILL WORK, it does the aggregation on the client side, rather than formulating appropriate SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I see this in first of your links, I think it is what you want:

```
query {
    for student in db.Student do
    groupValBy student.Name student.Age into g
    select (g, g.Key, g.Count())
}
```

Comment: groupValBy is described as "Selects a value for each element selected so far and groups the elements by the given key." The key is this case is still just based on student.Name

Comment: So, why is there that student.Age? I can't believe there is no easy way to group by multiple columns in FSharp. Similar case I see now in join - how to write composite key?

Comment: Actually this will group only by `student.Age`.  The first arg `groupValBy` is the value which will be stored, the second is the key to group by.  Imagine the word `by` between the first and second args.

Answer (score 1):

```
//in F# 3.0
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter
open System.Linq

//[<CLIMutable>]
//type MyRecord = { Column1 : int; Column2 : int }
// require constructor in F#
// groupBy is not valid

type T(column1 : int, column2 : int)
    member val Colum1=colum1 with get,set
    membre val Colum2=colum2 with get,set

query {
    for d in context.table do
    groupValBy d (NewAnonymousObjectHelper(T(d.Colum1,d.Colume2))) into g
    select (g.Key)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remember that a query is translated into actual `SQL` at some point. It appears that linq does not support the use of multiple group keys as a `Tuple<>`. Therefore any transformation into `Tuple<>` has to be done after the database call has completed.

Second, you should be able to achieve **multiple key grouping** by performing multiple groupings behind each other on the respective keys:

```
query {
    for d1 in context.table do
    groupBy d1.col1 into g1
    for d2 in g1 do
    groupBy d2.col2 into g2
    select g2
}
```

Please have mercy with me if the syntax is not 100% since F# is not my native tongue :) The concept however should work just fine.

Comment: Interestingly enough still get "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Answer (score 0):

When using groupBy you need to select an aggregating function (e.g. count, sum, avg...).

Comment: The example is really just for illustration, using select (g.Key) isn't useful but should work... "select (g.Count())" gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
open System.Linq

query {
    for d in context.table do
    let t = MutableTuple<_,_>(Item1=d.col1,Item2=d.col2)
    groupValBy d t into g
    select (g.Key,g.Count())
    }
```

Comment: Seems to work. However having trouble getting anything beyond select (g.Key). select (g.Count()) gives an error and I'm not sure how to go about doing aggregation on other columns. Still playing with the idea though

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there may be a solution as indicated in by using a combination of `groupValBy` and `AnonymousObject<_,_>` from the [Linq RuntimeHelpers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/runtimehelpers.anonymousobject-class-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

ex.

```
query {
    for d in context.table do
    let key = AnonymousObject<_,_>(d.col1,d.col2)
    groupValBy d key into g
    select (g.Key)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
query {  
    for d in context.table do  
    groupBy (new {d.col1, d.col2}) into g  
    select (g.Key) 
}
```

Comment: Please add comments to help the asker understand. Otherwise this is "magic".

Comment: `new {d.col1, d.col2}` constructs a C# anonymous type; this is not valid F#.