# Entity Framework Core GroupBy Date

Tags: linq, f#, entity-framework-core

In C# you can group by `.Date`:

```
db.History.GroupBy(x => x.Timestamp.Date)
          .Select(g => new { key = g.Key, aggregate = g.Count() })
```

However, the equivalent F# does not work:

```
db.History.GroupBy(fun x -> x.Timestamp.Date)
          .Select(fun g -> { Date = g.Key; Count = g.Count()} )
```

The relevant record:

```
type DateCount = {
    Date: DateTime
    Count: int
}
```

It throws the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression `'DbSet<HistoryEntity>
>       .GroupBy(
>           source: h => copyOfStruct => copyOfStruct.Date.Invoke(h.Timestamp), 
>           keySelector: h => h)'` could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

How can I group by date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So in C#, when you use LINQ-to-SQL *queries*, you are using the extension methods on `IQueryable<T>`. If we look at the signature of say, the `GroupBy` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___), you will see that the function signature is actually

```
IQueryable<TSource>.GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> keySelector)
```

What's going on? `Expression<>` is a special type - when the C# compiler spots an `Expression<>` type, the compiler builds an AST, and passes the AST object (of type `Expression<Func<>>`), instead of the usual delegate. The underlying functions are expected to inspect the AST and build whatever query expression is finally needed, like SQL for querying the database.

You can try it yourself:

```
Expression<Func<int>> getRandom = () => 4; //random, chosen by fair dice roll
```

You can inspect the properties of `getRandom` to see the AST.
Since the magic happens in the C# compiler, when you do it in F#, this won't cut it.

To go into more detail, the F# compiler can recognize the `Expression<>`, but it does so by applying an implicit F# quotation - so you get an F# quotation wrapped method call that translates to the C# expression tree. (Sorry if, that was run on.)

F# has its own query comprehension [builder for SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions). It lets you write the  computation expressions like that of `seq` which translate to SQL queries. This works like you'd expect.

```
query {
    for record in db do
    select record
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks Asti.

Answer (score 0):

Group by `.Date` works when using in a query expression.

```
query {
    for h in db.History do
    groupValBy h h.Timestamp.Date into g
    select {
        Date  = g.Key
        Count = g.Count()
    }
}
```

Code stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826263).

If someone could explain why the query expression works but the LINQ version doesn't, I'd appreciate it :)